# Including target/classes/* of current project into maven plugin execution classpath for bytecode instrumention with ASM

Tags: java, maven, classpath, maven-plugin

I am trying to write a maven plugin which is when added to a project, will instrument this project' classes bytecode. The problem i am facing is that ASM (the tool for JVM bytecode manipulation) tries to class-load classes it is instrumenting for some reason and classloader of ASM jars is missing those classes, because they were compiled just a few seconds before my maven plugin execution and liying in target/classes directory of current project.

How it is possible to append a target/classes directory of current project to maven plugin execution classpath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since **Maven 3**, **plugin classloader is more isolated**. It only contains the plugin dependencies.
It **does not contain current project dependencies or build output**. [See here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-maven-classloading.html) for the official doc about that.

You will have to create a classloader containing what you need. Maven API provides several ways to get what you need, [see for instance some examples in that SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871708/maven-plugin-cant-load-class)).
You can surely also get good examples from recent versions of [maven-exec-plugin](https://github.com/mojohaus/exec-maven-plugin), which obviously has to handle this issue.